# Crossplatform HTTP server lib

Tags: c, http, https

I need lib which would handle simple HTTP GET/PUT requests on a server side.
There are some special requirements:

- It should be crossplatform(This is main factor)
- Support of multithreading.
- High performance
- Support of HTTPS
- Licence should permit linking with proprietary code(LGPL, BSD)

Currently my top choice is [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/).
But it require MinGW on Windows, which I prefer not to add
as dependency of my program.
Maybe someone can suggest other libraries, which meet my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a complete solution, you could try something like [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) or [liblacewing](http://lacewing-project.org).

Alternatively, just hook up a [decent HTTP parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser) with whatever you prefer for socket I/O (such as [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv), ...)